# Cartesian products of lists without duplicates

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array `a=['a','b','c']`, how would you go about returning the Cartesian product of the array without duplicates. Example:

```
[['a', 'a' , 'a' ,'a']
['a', 'a' , 'a' ,'b']
['a', 'a' , 'a' ,'c']
['a', 'a' , 'b' ,'b']
['a', 'a' , 'b' ,'c']
['a', 'a' , 'c' ,'c']
...etc..]
```

Following [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python), I tried :

```
print list(itertools.permutations(['a', 'b' , 'c'], 4))
[]

print list(itertools.product(['a', 'b' , 'c'], repeat=4)
```

But I get the Cartesian product with duplicates. For example the list will contain both `['a','a','b','b']` and `['a','b','b','a']` which are clearly the equal.

Note: my 'a','b','c' are variables which store numbers say 1,2,3. So after getting the list of combinations of the letters, I would need to: say,

```
['a','b','c','c'] ----> a*b*c*c = 1*2*3*3 = 18
```

What is the fastest way of doing this in python? Would it be possible/faster to do it with numpy??
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit**: Don't use this; use the other answer

---

If your original set is guaranteed uniqueness, then the `combinations_with_replacement` solution will work. If not, you can first pass it through `set()` to get it down to unique variables. Regarding the product, assuming you have the values stored in a dictionary `values` and that all the variables are valid python identifiers, you can do something like the following

```
combos = combinations_with_replacement(a, 4)
product_strings = ['*'.join(c) for c in combos]
products = [eval(s, globals(), values) for s in product_strings]
```

Needless to say, be very careful with `eval`. Only use this solution if you are creating the list `a`.

Example exploit: `a = ['from os import', '; system("rm -rf .");']`

Comment: i dont get what does eval(s, globals(), values) do ??

Comment: The string you're passing in is something like `"a*b*c*d"`. When you `eval` it, the second argument is a local dictionary to use. Eg, `{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}`. It tells python the values of each of your variables.

Comment: To anyone reading this answer in the future (since it's the top answer): any time you are thinking of using `eval`, pump the brakes. It's generally a bad idea. Use the other answer.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you actually want [combinations_with_replacement](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)?

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> c = combinations_with_replacement(a, 4)
>>> for x in c:
...     print x
...     
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'c', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'b', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'c', 'c')
('b', 'b', 'b', 'b')
('b', 'b', 'b', 'c')
('b', 'b', 'c', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'c', 'c')
('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')
```

Without more information about how you're mapping strings to numbers I can't comment on your second question, but writing your own `product` function or using `numpy`'s isn't too difficult.